# displaying the list of currently running task's packages and classes in my android application

Tags: android, android-activity, package

here is the scenario that i want to display the list of currently running task's packages and classes in my android application,i have written a code but it is giving me run time error..can anyone help me to solve this..
Below is my code....is my idea is correct or i don't mind if another code for this program..

```
ActivityManager actM = null;
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> Runningtasks= actM.getRunningTasks(5);
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ComponentName comName=Runningtasks.get(i).topActivity;
    String Packname = comName.getPackageName();
    String Classname = comName.getClassName();
    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, Packname, duration);
    toast1.show();
}
```

Comment: And what is the runtime error it is giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you need to initialize actM by getting yourself an activity manager instance:

```
ActivityManager actM = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

For another, you seem not to have any protection against the possibility that one of these functions may return a null object - you have to verify that it hasn't before you try to call a method of the object in question.  For example, what if there are less than 5 running tasks?

(Incidentally, the information returned is not considered to be fully reliable - it's more of a curiosity API than one you can depend on)

Comment: according to the below link,i need to get android.permission.GET_TASKS permission from manifest.permission class..plz help me how to get it.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Comment: would you plz tel me what code i need to insert in manifest file

Comment: should i get permission through manifest file or from my java file..?